# How to build a secure captcha using jQuery UI Slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, captcha, salt

I'd like to build a fancy and easy to use captcha for my registration by using a slider on which the user can proof he is a human and no script.

So far I implemented the slider with jQuery UI Slider, if the value is 100 the submit-button will be appear. Looks good and I'm satified with the behaviour.

BUT since JS is executed by the client everyone is able to see my code and can trigger the same actions by using a script. For scripts there is no difference if the button is available or not. Scripts only post data to submit forms and my slider-captcha is useless.

My simple JS-code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value:0,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if(ui.value == 100){
                    $( "#amount" ).val( "human" );
                    $("#regButton").slideDown();
                } else if (ui.value == 50) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( "nerd" );
                    $("#regButton").slideUp();
                } else {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( "script" );
                    $("#regButton").slideUp();
                }
            }
        });
        $("#regButton").hide();
        $( "#amount" ).val( "Script" );
    });
```

HTML:

```
<label for="amount" style="text-align:right;">I'm a:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; width: 197px;" />
        <div id="slider"></div>
```

Are there possibilities to build the captcha saver? Using serverside hashes? Setting flags? what are practises to archive security with a fancy UI and a little more user experince than entering letters.

I'm using Java EE with Spring MVC on the serverside. Whould be nice to use a slider instead of reCaptcha eg.

---

EDIT: I added a hash value to the slider logic. At the begin the server rendering a hidden-field with the date on which the registration started, the server build a md5-hash based on this date. Was the slider moved a function is called which reads the value of the hiddenfield and build an md5-hash, too. The hashvalue will be send to the server and before submitting the registration compared against the servervalue of the hash. Not as save as text-captchas but even more effective than doing nothing at all.

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/slidelock/

What do you thing? How do this guy build a "safe" slider? How he manage the serverside validation and the SALT? Is it safe or also only more expensive for scripter to crack it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an existing captcha component instead of writing own?

There are plenty of them out there. I would recommend http://www.google.com/recaptcha, which is free and helps with books digitalization.

Comment: First reason is that I need all on my servers, second its about a nice solution which isn't boring and provids a bit of userexperience even in the registration form. Yes, I know that reCaptcha is reliable and customizable and support different languages. I like to know how to build a captcha, there should be people outside of google knowing about how to :)

Comment: I would like to add the reCaptcha also help ditigize books as the same time, which is pretty neat. So the captchas are actually serving a purpose other than protecting your site.

Comment: Standard captchas on mobile are terribad. A slider approach is sexy, but needs enhanced security implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Jumped to conclusions and posted what I shouldn't, sorry.

I completely understand your desire to have it custom built, especially when it is so easy to do. But I don't see anything inherently wrong with using a slider captcha so long as it is not the only means of securing a form/application. I think it can easily be augmented to have unique identifiers, and I think it's far superior in ease of use. I plan to use it in my future applications after I test it and research more.